# Black lines in imported UV layout

Tags: texturing, uv, export, import, svg

I exported the UV layout as an svg file with a resolution of 2048 by 2048. I chose export all UVs and set the fill opacity to 1. I then applied colors to the UV layout in Inkscape and saved the file as a png. I then imported the UV layout as a diffuse texture and saw black lines along the edges of my model:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the black lines in my model. I am using Blender version 2.82a. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you've forgot to disable the UV layout in Inkscape before exporting as png right? UV layout is just a visual helper for texturing and there is no reason to keep it for the actual texture.

Comment: How do I disable the UV layout in Inkscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UV layout is just a visual guide for texturing and there is no reason to keep it for the actual texture.*

#### Basic UV layout workflow

The principles are the same for all editing tools on how to use the uv-layout no matter it is Inkscape, Photoshop, Affinity Designer, Gimp or whatever:

1. Export your UV-Layout out of Blender *(UV Editor > UV > Export UV Layout)*, either as vector `svg` or image file (`png`)
2. Open up the file in your favourite editing tool
3. Create a new layer and give it any meaningful name like 'UV-Layout'
4. Place your UV-Layout onto that new layer and drag it on top of the stack
5. Set 'Blend-Mode' of the UV layer to 'Multiply' which basically allows to *"see trough"* the 'unfold geometry' and having the layout as reference in place:
   [image]
6. To avoid moving the layer by accident lock your 'UV-Layout' layer by clicking the little *lock-icon*
7. Create your textures somewhere below that layer eg. in another layer called 'texture'
8. *When done with texturing:* *disable* your 'UV-Layout' layer by clicking the eye or stack icon left to the lock icon and *export* it as image file (eg. `png`, `exr` or `jpg`)
9. Back in Blender, load up the image in the *Image Editor* *(Image > Open)* to check for issues:

   [image]
   *UV Editor vs Image Editor*
10. Final step is to assign the image texture to the shader and set the viewport shading to *Material Preview* or even to *Rendered* to see the actual result:

    [image]